# Encoding problem with Portuguese characters while opening shapefile

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3, encoding, portugal

I use a shapefile with names in Portuguese that contain special characters. When I add it to QGIS it exchanges special characters for symbols, so I have problems when comparing values with other layers.

I use QGIS - 3.8.3 Zanzibar on Ubuntu 18.04. So how can I correctly encode the special characters in the shapefile?

Comment: Do you know the original encoding? Have you tried to open it with the same in QGIS? What about `ISO-8859-1`?

Comment: Yes, I just change for ISO 8859-1 and worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Taras I think it is better to add your comment as an answer with some elaboration.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is suggested to explore the original file, perhaps it was already encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) or any local Unicode Standard applied automatically by OS, from my experience Windows likes such practice.

Secondly, it is possible to apply one of the Standards for Western alphabetic languages, in particular [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), which includes Portuguese (European and Brazilian).

[image: example]

---

**References:**

- [Portuguese encoding Ã£, Ãª, Ã§, Ã¡](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52749834/portuguese-encoding-%C3%83%C2%A3-%C3%83%C2%AA-%C3%83-%C3%83)
- [File encoding for Portuguese-Brazilian](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/File-encoding-for-Portuguese-Brazilian/qaq-p/680609)
- [The ISO 8859 Series](https://www.terena.org/activities/multiling/ml-docs/iso-8859.html)