# Can't read a shapefile in geopandas due to encoding

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, geopandas, arcgis-10.5

I'm working with ArGIS Desktop 10.5 and python 2.7, and just installed geopandas to try it out.
However, when I tried to read a shapefile, I received an encoding error:

```
import arcpy
import geopandas as gpd

data = gpd.read_file(r"<file_path_here>.shp", encoding='utf-8')
```

I know the shapefile has special characters (portuguese text), but I don't understand why the UTF-8 encoding is not working. I have never changed any default encoding properties. How could I fix this problem? Is there a way to check the shapefile's encoding?

Edit: sorry, I forgot the error message

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 76, in read_file
    with reader(path_or_bytes, **kwargs) as features:
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 398, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 257, in open
    layer=layer, enabled_drivers=enabled_drivers, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.session.start(self, **kwargs)
  File "fiona\ogrext.pyx", line 466, in fiona.ogrext.Session.start
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 34: ordinal not in range(128)
```

These are the packages' versions I was able to install (using wheels from lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona)

> - GDAL-2.2.4-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
> - pyproj-1.9.6-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
> - Fiona-1.8.13-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
> - Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
> - geopandas-0.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl

For some reason, python 2.7 won't upgrade/ accept geopandas for version 10...

Comment: Python 2.7 ? Is it still alive ? Ooo … I forgot it is ESRI. Can you read the shape file with Portuguese encoding?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/339883/99589

Comment: I can't...
I have tried these: utf-8, latin-1, ISO 8859-1
None worked. I don't know how ArcGIS is encoding this shapefile.

Comment: Can you share your data here?

Comment: No, I can't.
I just opened the file in QGIS, and it says the encoding is UTF-8
That's weird...

Comment: Can you run this tool in QGIS : https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#extract-shapefile-encoding. What does it say?

Comment: could it be the version of Fiona or geopandas?

Comment: I do not think so, but which version of GeoPandas or Fiona are you using ?

Comment: I ran the tool on QGIS, this is the results: `{'CPG_ENCODING': 'UTF-8', 'ENCODING': 'UTF-8', 'LDID_ENCODING': NULL}`. I was able to install geopandas 0.6.2 and fiona 1.8.13, using wheels

Comment: What if you upgrade both GeoPandas (0.10.2) and Fiona (1.8.21)? What happens if you `data = gpd.read_file(r"<file_path_here>.shp")` without encoding?

Comment: I tried upgrading, but it didn't work. I think recent versions of geopandas won't work with Python 2.7...

Comment: you are right! There should be a compatibility with Python 2.7 : geopandas‑0.10.2‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl and Fiona‑1.8.13‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona

Comment: I will add the packages versions on the question

Comment: Have you opened the *.cpg file in notepad to see which encoding it says?

Comment: It just says UTF-8

Comment: Maybe the shapefile is broken

Comment: I opened the same shapefile on QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop, and it worked fine

Comment: Try Repair shapefile in QGIS then try again. Can you share the shapefile, I can try if my geopandas can read it?